# How to target multiple frameworks for a library

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj

I am making this Standard Library to target according to the downloaded framework. For example for .NET Core it will download the packages that are for .NET Core

```
 <!--Trageting .NET CORE (2.1, 3.0) && .NET STANDARD (2.0,2.1) -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netcore')) OR $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard')) ">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
    <!--<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" Version="5.2.7" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <!--Targeting .NET FRAMEWORK (4.6.1 4.6.2)  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462'">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

   <!--Targeting .NET FRAMEWORK (4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2)-->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47' &#xD;&#xA; OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471'&#xD;&#xA; OR '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net472'">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.5.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsEventLog" Version="4.6.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.EventLog" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there any better way of doing this above code as mentioned like using DefineConstants?

Comment: you can't target multiple frameworks in a single project.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker yes you can; it is pretty normal for libraries

Comment: Only if all libraries adhere to the same .Net standard specification.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker no, sorry but that is simply wrong; the **entire point** of multi-targeting is to target *incompatible* frameworks (well... note; you can *also* use it to target sub/super-TFMs, using additional features in the super-TFM when available); seriously: `<TargetFrameworks>` is a thing; as an example, expand "Dependencies" [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.4.4) - this is a single csproj, built once only, but with 8 output TFMs, with many differences in the dependency chains

Comment: @GlennvanAcker we can infer here that the project *is already* targeting multiple frameworks, with different (and non-trivial) dependency chains depending on the TFM; the point of the question is to simplify this per-TFM configuration

Comment: Thats possible because it was adding the packing according to the target framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the thing you want to change is the *versions* with them having some amount of commonality, then I might be tempted to do something like:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionWebApiClient>5.2.3</VersionWebApiClient>
    <VersionWebApiClient Condition="...todo...">5.2.7</VersionWebApiClient>
    <!-- ... for the other things ... -->
<PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="$(VersionWebApiClient)" />
    <!-- ... for the other things ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

This:

1. allows the most common values to be simple defaults
2. allows clear overrides per target framework
3. doesn't duplicate the actual package references

Comment: @AamirNaeem the only thing missing is the condition, which you already seem to have?

Comment: Marc Gravell that looks amazing but you please provide me link related to it or could you please make changes in the code that I have mentioned above so I could a clear cut idea :) @Marc Gravell